# Using v-for with nested object in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have data in this form:

```
itemlist : {
  "dates": [
    "2019-03-15", 
    "2019-04-01", 
    "2019-05-15"
  ], 
  "id": [
    "arn21", 
    "3sa4a", 
    "wqa99"
  ], 
  "price": [
    22, 
    10, 
    31
  ]
}
```

I want to use v-for in my created component that loops through this object treating every index in those 3 nested arrays as one observation. So `dates[0]`, `id[0]` and `price[0]`correspond to same item, dates[1] id[1] price[1] is second and so on.

So In other words I think I need to transform this into, but not sure:

```
0 : {
dates: "2019-03-15", 
id: "arn21", 
price: 22,}
1:{
dates: "2019-04-01", 
id: "3sa4a", 
price: 10}
}
2:...
```

Thats how I pass the data to the component:

```
<tempc v-for="i in itemlist" :key="i.id" :price="i.price" :dates="i.dates"></temp>
```

But this does not work for the original data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a **computed** property for this:

```js
Vue.component('my-component', {
  template: '#my-component',
  data() {
    return {
      itemlist: {
        "dates": [
          "2019-03-15",
          "2019-04-01",
          "2019-05-15"
        ],
        "id": [
          "arn21",
          "3sa4a",
          "wqa99"
        ],
        "price": [
          22,
          10,
          31
        ]
      }
    };
  },
  computed: {
    // Note: here I assume these arrays will always have the same length
    mergedList() {
      return this.itemlist.dates.map((dates, i) => {
        return {
          dates,
          id: this.itemlist.id[i],
          price: this.itemlist.price[i]
        };
      });
    }
  }
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.21/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <my-component></my-component>
</div>

<template id="my-component">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="i in mergedList" :key="i.id" :price="i.price" :dates="i.dates">
      {{i.id}} - ${{i.price}} ({{i.dates}})
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```